# When scanning a QR code I want to check if the value exists in my database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have implemented a QR code scanner that when I scan a QR code I get an `AlertDialog`. What I want is when I scan a QR code with the value of 2 (Example), I want the application to check if the value exists in my `Database`. If it does, I want to set the title in my `AlertDialog` to the `"toolname"` value from my `Database`.

I have actually done this before, but since I'm new to this I don't remember how I did it.
Hopefully, someone could help me out.

Here is my structure:

[image: Firebase]
[image: Firebase database]

Here is my code for the QR scanner:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    IntentResult intentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
            requestCode, resultCode, data
    );


    if (intentResult.getContents() != null) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        builder.setMessage("Hello");

        builder.setTitle("Here I want the name of the item in my database");

        builder.show();

    }
}
```

Here is how I read data from firebase:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("").getReference("Ansatte");
    databaseTools = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(").getReference("Fellesverktøy");


    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    DatabaseReference hasUserStorageRef = databaseUsers.child(currentUser).child("hasusersstorage");

    userloggedin = findViewById(R.id.tv_userloggedin);
    bttoaddtool = findViewById(R.id.bt_addtool);
    bttoollist = findViewById(R.id.bt_toollist);
    btusertoollist = findViewById(R.id.bt_usertoollist);
    btlogoutuser = findViewById(R.id.bt_logoutuser);
    ivqrscan = findViewById(R.id.iv_qrscan);

    hasUserStorageRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    String hasusersstorage = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    if (hasusersstorage.equals("Nei")) {

                        bttoaddtool.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btusertoollist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else if (hasusersstorage.equals("Ja")) {
                        bttoaddtool.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btusertoollist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Updated code:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    IntentResult intentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Query query = databaseTools;

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            builder.setTitle(intentResult.getContents());

            String toolid = snapshot.getValue().toString();

            builder.setMessage(toolid);


            builder.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: There is nothing in your code related to how you read data from the Realtime Database. Can show us what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, I've added more code from that 'Activity'. I can show you an example of what I've been trying.

Comment: There is a call to `.child(currentUser)` but we cannot see it in your screenshot. Cam you please add a more detailed one?

Comment: That is because that is a different database, it is for `"Ansatte`. But with the QR scanner it is the database for `Fellesverktøy` I use. I will add more details in the original post.

Comment: I have added more info, what I actually want to display in my `AlertDialog` is the toolname that have the same `ID` as the barcode I have scanned.

Comment: With the last update, the `ÀlertDialog` is missing the `setTitle` value. So everything inside the `ValueEventListener` is not showing.

Comment: What is the value of `scan` inside your reference? What is the value of `toolqr` inside onDataChange? Besides thatl, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: The value of `scan` is the barcode value that I scan. And the `toolqr` is supposed to be the  value of `child` `"toolQRid"`. So if the scanned value `scan` is equal to `toolqr` I want to get the value from the child `"toolname"`. And about these `Log.d`, I am so new to this, I know it's important  to not ignore errors. But I don't fully understand where to use them.

Comment: If you add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());` inside onCancelled, do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: No, nothing that seems to be any errors. So I don't know what to do. It looks to me that I can't use `builder.setTitle` inside onDataChange. The stupid thing here is that I've done this before, but I deleted that code for many years ago and I don't remember. Just for information, here is the youtube video for the QR scanner: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2pgSu9RhYo&t=320s

Comment: What does this line print `String toolqr = snapshot.child("toolQRid").getValue().toString();`?

Comment: I think it does nothing. But what I am trying to achieve is to get the value from the `Database`. I have tried so many different things but no luck yet. In my head it supposed to be easy. When I scan a barcode the `alertdialog` pops up with a `setMessage` with the value of the barcode. The value of the barcode I want to relate to the value inside the `child` "toolQRid". So if the value exists in my database, I want to `setTitle` with the value of the `child` "toolname" from the same database.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread, how to I set a `Log` on that line?

Comment: Have you tried to use hard-coded values in your reference? Does it work that way?

Comment: I've tried to set a fixed value inside OnDataChange. For example: `builder.setTitle("Hello")`. But the alert dialog don't show when it is inside av that OnDataChange.

Comment: Is your OnDataChange even called?

Comment: Hi again, new update. The code that I updated works in a way. When I scan and QR code now, I get everything from that `database` as `builder.setMessage`. But when I change `String toolid = snapshot.getValue().toString();` to `String toolid = snapshot.child("toolQRid").getValue().toString();` I get this error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Ok, I'll try to provide an answer right away.

Comment: A little update, when I change this: `query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {` to this `query.orderByChild("toolQRid").equalTo(intentResult.getContents()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {` I manage to get only the data from the id 2 in my firebase. So "Fellesverktøy" - "2" - And everything here. So we are on the right way. Just need to only get one value from `child`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of `toolname` field when searching the Firebase Database, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference productsRef = db.child("Fellesverktøy").orderByChild("toolQRid").equalTo("2");
    productsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String toolName = ds.child("toolname").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", toolName);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
heipadeg
```

Now, you can take this value and add it as a title to your  AlertDialog.

Comment: This code works, so I will manage to make the rest work. Thank you for taking the time to answer.